# Short trip to Mexico and return to the US

Tags: usa, mexico

I entered the US on the emergency visa waiver B2 as I travelled earlier than expected to the US, I am planning to come to Mexico and have a one-day trip and then return with my H1B on date (already stamped in my passport).

May I ask is it possible for such travel? I am wondering if is it okay to come to Mexico and return with the H1B? Does any foresee any problem?

Thank you very much!

Comment: This is answered in the comments on https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/22659/2440.

Comment: Thank you I am wondering if my status B2 with the H1B stamp but not ready to be effective, the H1B has the expiration date of oct 2022, I am holding a Vietnamese passport, can I come to Mexico? (In the post I did not mention I am Vietnamese)